# Новый CSS в медиа запросах отображается не верно на хостинге

Tags: javascript, html, css, sass

Проблема такая, на локальной машине и на гитхабе сайт выглядит как надо, но как только я заливаю сайт на хостинг, некоторые css стили не срабатывают, пути указываю так

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/style.css" />
```

''[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

ссылка на гит pages [ТЫК](https://maxkolink.github.io/sk3/)
ссылка на реп [ТЫК](https://github.com/MaxKoLink/sk3)

Comment: Забыли почистить кэш в браузере?

Comment: Как же я вас люблю, все заработало